# Matching raster graphics and PS colors

Tags: color, pstricks, eps

I have a need to match colors in the originaly raster EPS graphics and background color. Relevant parts of the code:

```
\usepackage[dvipsnames,prologue,table]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-text}
\usepackage{graphicx}

...

\newsavebox\LBox
\sbox\LBox{\includegraphics[height=9.23mm]{logo.eps}}  % raster

\newcmykcolor{reddish}{.0 .7 0.89 .16}
```

The end result is a PDF (through dvi, ps).

Also tried using same RBG in both eps and LaTeX markup. It even prints fine on my own color printer, but not elsewhere. Fortunately, there is no need to have exact color, just match EPSs background with the rest of the layout background.

Update:

The question is, how do I specify the same color by newcmykcolor (or newrgbcolor) and the color of png (which I convert then to eps)? I am using GIMP. GIMP has CMYK specification, but it is not in .0 .7 0.89 .16 mode, but rather 0-100 range.

I have tried to use the same RGB colors (in LaTeX and png/eps), for example, and it works for some printers.

In any case, does this require use of color profiles or how to get naive approach to work (I do not need exact color, just same).

Comment: So what is the question here? You have an EPS file and you want to find out which colours were used in some parts? For example, did you find the CMYK values for `reddish` through trial-and-error, but you want a more sounds way of finding them?

Comment: Some photo editors have a tool to know the RGB or CMYK values for a sampled point on the given picture. Have you done it yet?

Comment: I have control over what to put into EPS file: its raster, made from png. On screen both colors are the same. The dissonance happens because (some) printer's software treats latex-generated background color differently from the colors from EPS. And I want to know the way, how to specify both colors reliably to the same value. I can't use trial-n-error approach, because my printer prints right - the problem happens when I send the file to be printed.

Comment: If you start with a PNG file using pdfTeX or LuaTeX would be a workaround to avoid the conversion to your CMYK EPS which is inherently coupled to some color profile.

Comment: Look into the eps if it defines rgb or cmyk colors. You have to choose the _same_ color model for the background color!

Comment: AFAIK, pstricks do not work with pdfLatex. EPS is actually raster.

Comment: it works with xelatex and also with pdflatex when using package `auto-pst-pdf`

Comment: thanks for the hint, but it doesn't work here (TexLive, Ubuntu)

Comment: If it is the full background (not clipped to paths within the eps), and you have control over the eps generation, you could just not colour the background in the eps, leaving it transparent, and then overlay that on a coloured background specified in the latex, that way all your colours are specified using the same implementation.

Comment: EPS doesn't work with transparency. Even though I have control over eps, I do not want to add clipped paths into there by hand. Transparency would solve my concrete problem, if worked properly.